# How to enable system level audits in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

am very new to mongoDB.
As part of Security Implementations in mongoDB, i need to enable system level audits.So i have added the following lines in mongod.conf.

```
auditLog:
destination: file
format: JSON
path: data/db/auditLog.json
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Even from the mongo shell am like:

```
mongo db --port <port number> -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase db --auditDestination data/db/auditLog.json.
```

still it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted within the MongoDB Documentation of the Audit feature, audit capability is limited to MongoDB's enterprise version.

http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/configure-auditing/

You will need to contact MongoDB to purchase their enterprise software.